# Angular ng-repeat and Sass conflict

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass

I am working right now on a project. Sadly I'm stuck at the following issue:

I am using ng-repeat to fill the list which forms the navigation bar and Sass to adjust the width of the list elements depending on the number of elements so the width  equally distributed.

It looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="leftViewNav" class="leftNav">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat= "leftNavTag in leftNavTags"><p>{{ leftNavTag.title }}</p></li>
            <li><p>add</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**SCSS**

```
li{
    position: relative;
    @for $i from 1 through 4 {
        li:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i}),
        li:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i}) ~ li {
            width: 100% / $i
        } }
    height: 5%;
}
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.leftNavTags =
[
    {
        title: 'Analysis',
    },
    {
        title: 'Log',
    },
    {
        title: 'Edit',
    }
];
```

**CSS**

```
.leftBound div ul li {
  position: relative;
  height: 5%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #C4C2C3;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
/* line 50, ../sass/main.scss */
.leftBound div ul li li:first-child:nth-last-child(1),
.leftBound div ul li li:first-child:nth-last-child(1) ~ li {
  width: 100%;
}
/* line 50, ../sass/main.scss */
.leftBound div ul li li:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.leftBound div ul li li:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ li {
  width: 50%;
}
/* line 50, ../sass/main.scss */
.leftBound div ul li li:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.leftBound div ul li li:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ li {
  width: 33.33333%;
}
/* line 50, ../sass/main.scss */
.leftBound div ul li li:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.leftBound div ul li li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ li {
  width: 25%;
}
```

So the first element has a width of 100%, the second 50% and so on.

How to solve this issue so elements have the same width?
Help is much .appreciated .

Edit: Clarified the question.
:

Comment: don't use :first-child, nth-last-child in css, use a proper class. and in angular you have $first, $last, $middle, $even, $odd within ng-repeat so that you can use with ng-class

Comment: @CTSK, It is not clear what you whant to achieve, elements wich decreasing width or elements with same width ? I cannot review pending edits to the question as long as it is not clear what OP needs

Comment: It's not clear here what the actual problem is.  This has nothing to do with Sass, Angular, or JavaScript:  it's a pure CSS problem.  How your markup/CSS is generated is irrelevant.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks the problem is understandable? Applying a `25%` width if there are 4 items, or `50%` width if there are two items is exactly what OP wants to achieve. For a first question I think it is not bad, well formatted, so for me it's an upvote. Oh and, @CTSK, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos It's the OP's job to distill the problem down to the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem.  The OP has added a lot of details that are irrelevant to the problem, making it more difficult to diagnose than necessary.  Don't upvote garbage like "I forgot to add the class name to my markup" (hint: that's a minor typographical error, and you should be voting to close those questions as such).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem #1:**

In the template, you have two `class` attributes:

```
<div class="leftViewNav" class="leftNav">
```

**Problem #2:**

The sass loop is too much nested. You are gererating styles for `.leftBound div ul li li`

**Problem #3:**

We don't see any `leftBound` class in the template.

---

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/q3ct5aee/)** of what you would get, providing you solve these three problems. (NB: added bootstrap `list-unstyled` class to *kill* default list style)

Comment: Thanks for solving my question. The Points mentioned in Problem #1 and #3 are referring to somewhere else inthe code. Problem #2 actually did the job. Thanks again